# How to align multiple images under <a href> tag?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I need to align 4 images which are acting as a link and these links are under a div tag. I am not quite sure how to align them perfectly because two in the left seem to be aligned but the ones in the right are causing the issue. Can I have some suggestions on how to fix this please. Currently this is how it looks like:I assumed all the components will be aligned properly since they are under a div tag with the same class name.

[image]

CSS

```
.pagelinks {
float: right;
margin-right: 48%;
display: inline-block;
}

.pagelinks a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

JSP/HTMl code

```
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<div class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} <a href="{3}"> | <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a><a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></div>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<div class="pagelinks"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> | Page {5} of {6} | <a href="{3}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a><a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/></a></div>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<div class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </div>'/>
```

Comment: And where is your html? Please provide a working example

Comment: Oops, I completely forgot. I edit my question.

Comment: But you didn't provide html/working demo

Comment: If it's JSP as well as HTML, you might want a JSP tag as well.

Comment: @Dekel, I've provided you the code and the image, what are you going to do with the demo? Whatever you get from the demo is already here.

Comment: @James, Html tags are inside jsp tags it shouldn't matter. CSS should still work right.

Comment: `display:setProperty` is not html, it's jsp. In order to understand the problem we need to see the output (which is the html).

Comment: This is what I am saying, don't worry about the jsp tags. It is a third party library and I am using it for a purpose. Inside this I have a div tag pagelinks and inside pagelinks I got the links.

Comment: Right-click the element in the browser and select Inspect Element. Find the closest element that contains all of the code you're asking about. Right click on that node and select Copy or Copy outerHTML. Believe it or not, we're actually trying to help you; we just need to know what HTML the *browser* is applying that CSS to in order to know what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the provided JSP snippet, your markup is not consistent, so make sure to check that. Next, expand your CSS to set the height and width of the images.

Check out this fiddle to see an example: https://jsfiddle.net/37f8n4v9/

CSS

```
.pagelinks img{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I liked it, but in you fiddle you put all the elements under one div tag while in my case I have to have them in three different divs this is because I am using some jsp properties. So if I use your snippet the images still appear the same. I think this is because I got three div tags right.

Comment: I copied the markup from the first JSP line in your snippet. Like I said, Inspect your markup a bit closer in each JSP element and that may also solve some of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

So guys, I figured it out for the image only. I changed the pixels of the image in the most right exactly the same as next to it 24 X 17. So the images appear aligned. Please take a look at the image below.
[image]